# How to CENTER shortcode in footer PHP WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, footer, shortcode

I need to **center** (tags)shortcode that I put in footer PHP.

I used this plugin [cool_tag_cloud] https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/cool-tag-cloud/

Code that I put in footer PHP `<?php echo do_shortcode('[cool_tag_cloud style="blue"]'); ?>`

How to center tags from this plugin in my footer?

Comment: sounds like you could do that with css

Comment: ok i tried to center div but doesnt work

Comment: Your shortcode is creating HTML. You must center that HTML with either HTML or CSS (or JS, I guess). No PHP can help you.

Comment: Normally i wouldn't ask this, since your not supposed to link to the website, but insted actually show us some code, and explain what you have tried - but it really does sound like it is an easy fix, so provide a link and explain what "center" means to you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very much like you just need to surround the output with a `<div>...</div>` that is minimal in size and that centers it self, something like this:

```
<div style="margin: 0px auto;width: 1px;"><?php echo do_shortcode('[cool_tag_cloud style="blue"]'); ?></div>
```

Kind of like (simulating)

```html
<div style="margin: 0px auto;width: 1px;"><div style="background-color: #0f0;height: 100px;width: 100px;"></div></div>
```

Comment: Glad we could help! Don't forget to mark the answer as solution/answered.